# Using Kafka Connect to Pull Data from an API with Dynamic Payload

Tags: http, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have an API that provides data based on an input payload, which includes country and week number. My objective is to retrieve data from this API and publish it to a Kafka topic. While I understand that I can create a custom producer application for this task, I am interested in exploring the possibility of achieving this using Kafka Connect.

I'm aware of the existence of HTTP source connectors for Kafka Connect, but I have not come across any clear examples demonstrating how to pass a dynamic payload when making requests to the API.

Has anyone successfully accomplished a similar task using Kafka Connect, especially when dealing with APIs that require dynamic payloads? Any guidance, examples, or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any dynamic settings would be exposed though *static* configuration or a timestamp that's changing per HTTP request.

For example, you'd set `country.code` in the connector config... But what value? You'd need a static list here, or otherwise lookup a list of countries then pick a random one before making the real request... Not all HTTP endpoints need a country code, so that property won't exist without you forking the connector and including it yourself

So, no, the specific example you've provided is unlikely to exist

Your other option would be to use AWS lambda / GCP Function sink connectors, for example, and pass exact parameters to them, then write your own HTTP trigger code there. Or otherwise try services like Airflow, Nifi, etc, not Kafka Connect

Comment: So in a nutshell, you recommend to write a custom producer application

Comment: Not necessarily. Kafka Connect can still be used. You can write your own  Source Connector rather than a producer, but a producer won't require a running Connect server process, obviously